# Error downloading/saving a remote ML model from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-mlkit, firebase-machine-learning

I'm using MLKit with iOS in a react native project.

Basically using this code: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/ios/label-images-with-automl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/ios/label-images-with-automl?authuser=0)

It used to work fine but now i get this error:

```
downloadModel: notificationDidFail: 
name = com.google.mlkit.notif.model-download-did-fail, 
object = Optional(<MLKModelDownloader: 0x281a86300>), 
userInfo = Optional([AnyHashable("MLKModelDownloadUserInfoKeyError"): Error Domain=com.google.mlkit Code=2 "Failed to save AutoML remote model labels file." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to save AutoML remote model labels file.}, AnyHashable("MLKModelDownloadUserInfoKeyRemoteModel"): name: lepidoptera_underside])
```

Xcode prints:
**[MLKit][I-MLK018012] AutoML remote model inference info contains no labels**

One model seems to work more often than the others.

This gets executed:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
  forName: .mlkitModelDownloadDidFail,
  object: nil,
  queue: nil
) { notification in
  self.failed("downloadModel: notification error: \(notification)")
}
```

The whole download model function:

```
func downloadModel() {
    guard let remoteModel = remoteModel else {
      failed("downloadModel: remoteModel error")
      return
    }

    let downloadConditions = ModelDownloadConditions(
      allowsCellularAccess: true,
      allowsBackgroundDownloading: true
    )

    _ = ModelManager.modelManager().download(
      remoteModel,
      conditions: downloadConditions
    )

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      forName: .mlkitModelDownloadDidSucceed,
      object: nil,
      queue: nil
    ) { [weak self] notification in
      guard let strongSelf = self,
            let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let model = userInfo[ModelDownloadUserInfoKey.remoteModel.rawValue]
              as? RemoteModel,
            model.name == strongSelf.modelName
      else { return }
      strongSelf.createLabeler()
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      forName: .mlkitModelDownloadDidFail,
      object: nil,
      queue: nil
    ) { notification in
      self.failed("downloadModel: notification error: \(notification)")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation provided (https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/ios/label-images-with-automl) contains outdated information. ML Kit has fully deprecated and removed the `GoogleMLKit/ImageLabelingAutoML` pod in its recent versions.  That pod is now replaced by the `GoogleMLKit/ImageLabelingCustom` pod.  The latest version of `MLKitImageLabelingCustom` pod is `1.2.0`. Please refer to the full migration guide here:

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/image-labeling/automl/migrate-automl